# how to extract red, green and blue channels of bitmap in Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap, android-image

I have a bitmap image loaded into memory as a Bitmap object. I can load this into a ImageView,do operations using Canvas and so forth.But for an algorithm that I'm using I need 3 channel grey scale bitmaps.
The below image is from an article written Eric Z Goodnight on How to Geek.The link is given below.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42393/rgb-cmyk-alpha-what-are-image-channels-and-what-do-they-mean/

[image]
As you can see in the grey scale images corresponding to each channels the  respective colour areas are brightest. How can I extract the grey scale images corresponding each channels from an Bitmap image in android? I require 3 bitmaps objects containing these 3 channel grey scales respectively.I have come across a method to create grey scale by setting saturation of ColorMatrix as 0.But it returns on one grey scale.Is there any way to get the grey scale images corresponding to the 3 channels?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I don't have much experience with ColorMatrices. Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A pixel in bitmap format is represented by a 4 bytes integer, which describe Alpha, Red, Green and Blue channels of that pixel. For extracting a particular channel, you can simply do a bitwise OR on every pixel, with the appropriate hex value.

For instance, `0xFFFF0000` represents max alpha (FF), max red (FF), zero green and zero blue. So the bitwise OR for every pixel, will result in the green and blue channels to be ignored, cause they are zero (00).

Anyway, the code might look like below for extracting the `red channel` :

```
for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) 
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) 
   {
       bitmap.setPixel(x, y, bitmap.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFFFF0000);
   }
}
```

consequently, the `green channel` can be obtained by :

```
 for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) 
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) 
   {
       bitmap.setPixel(x, y, bitmap.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFF00FF00);
   }
}
```

and the `blue channel` :

```
for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) 
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) 
   {
       bitmap.setPixel(x, y, bitmap.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFF0000FF);
   }
}
```

Finally, to display the image in grayscale you can use the ColorMatrix for the imageview widget :

```
    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
    matrix.setSaturation(0);

    ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
    imageView.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will try this out and will post my results too. I hope this post will help a lot of other developers out there.

Comment: Just to know whether you mean bitwise-AND instead of bitwise-OR?